# Como puedo realizar esta expresion regular en php?

Tags: php

Estoy empezando a realizar un motor de plantillas super simple, y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de tomar el valor dentro de las llaves es decir: {{nombre}}, quiero tomar los valores que esten dentro de las llaves para ir guardandolos en un array, pero cabe recalcar que tambien soy nuevo en expresiones regulares, se lo basico pero esto de tomar el valor de la cadena entre las llaves no se como seria, gracias :)

Comment: Por favor, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que las expresiones regulares son abstracciones de valores reales, de forma abstracta debes decirle que es lo que quieres buscar en una cadena y cuales son sus caracteristicas.

Si intentas la siguiente expresion regular deberia funcionar.

```
\{{2}[\w\s?]+\}{2}
```

Lo que le estas diciendo es que esperas recibir dos llaves, una cadena con o sin espacios de longitud `n` y dos llaves de cierre.

Ahora para obtenerlo en php debes hacer uso de la funcion [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) de la siguiente manera

```
$s = '{{Cadena de prueba}}';
$matches = array();
$s = preg_match('/^\{{2}[\w\s?]+\}{2}$/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

La salida esperada deberia ser la siguiente

```
Cadena de prueba
```

Puedes hacer pruebas de tus expresiones regulares en [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

### Edicion

Primera forma:
Lo puedes hacer sin necesidad de regex con

```
$s = '{{Cadena de prueba}}';
echo substr($s, 2,-2);
```

Segunda forma

Modificando un poco el codigo anterior quedaria como lo siguiente

```
$s = '{{Cadena de prueba}}';
preg_match("~^\{{2}(?<string>.*?)\}{2}~",$s,$m);
echo $m["string"];
```

Con lo cual la salida de ambos metodos es

```
Cadena de prueba
```

Comment: hola!, lo probe y sale {{cadena de prueba}}, con las llaves

Comment: Acabo de modificar